# Translate htaccess into web.config

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config

I've a website built on apache and I've to migrate it into IIS. I don't know nothing about web.config, but I've a very simple .htaccess to translate.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot
Bye